# Create <:<-like implicit in Scala with custom inheritance structure

Tags: scala, implicit, implicits

I have a sealed `Entity` trait that can be either `Root` or `Descendant[P <: Entity]`. So I need a way to check that inheritance in function invocations. The most common Scala way is to require an implicit evidence of some type (`A <:< B` for plain Scala types, and something like `A <#< B` for entity ones). The main problem is to create implicit functions that will provide these evidences and will not confuse the compiler when it will try to resolve it.

---

Base snippet of code is:

```
sealed trait Entity
class Root extends Entity
class Descendant[P <: Entity] extends Entity

sealed trait <#<[From, To]

def check[F <: Entity, T <: Entity](implicit ev: F <#< T): Unit = {}
```

And test data for it:

```
object TRoot extends Root
object TBase extends Descendant[TRoot.type]
object TSub extends Descendant[TBase.type]

check[TRoot.type, TRoot.type]
check[TBase.type, TRoot.type]
check[TSub.type, TRoot.type]
```

---

One of solutions that I tried was to provide these implicit values:

```
trait Descendant[P <: Entity] { type Parent = P }

// In some parent object, so it will have lower priority
def childConforms[T <: Entity, D <: Descendant[_, _]](implicit ev: D#Parent <#< T):
          (D <#< T) = // create instance, e.g. from singleton

// In child object with higher priority than `childConforms`
def selfConforms[T <: Entity): (T <#< T) = // ...
```

But it seems that compiler is not able to correctly infer `D#Parent` (it infers as anonymous `_$1`, while it should infer as concrete parent type of `D`), so conversion does not work.

Another possibly dirty hack is to explicitly create a set of functions that will handle inheritance trees with fixed depths, thus limiting inheritance depth with amount of functions. This is possibly solution, but quite dirty.

```
def selfConforms[T <: Entity]: (T <#< T) = ...
def child1Conforms[T <: Entity, D <: Descendant[T]]: (D <#< T) = ...
def child2Conforms[T <: Entity, D <: Descendant[Descendant[T]]]: (D <#< T) = ...
// and so on
```

The third possible solution is a macro-based one, but it has a significant amount of drawbacks, such as complexity and requirement for separate compilation unit, so it can be considered only as fallback one.

---

The question is — how to properly implement implicit values which compiler will be able to resolve?